# Android XML > issue

Tags: android

I am having an issue and getting this error

Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

and here is the code it is giving it to me with

```
<activity
        android:name="com.zhecom.example.modulegeo.MainActivity       android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you need an end quote (") after android:name="com.zhecom.example.modulegeo.MainActivity

Comment: `This question was caused by (...) a simple typographical error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:name="com.zhecom.example.modulegeo.MainActivity
```

You are missing a `"` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

change this `android:name="com.zhecom.example.modulegeo.MainActivity`
to this `android:name="com.zhecom.example.modulegeo.MainActivity"`
you forgot to put " at the end